# Storing array Double[][] or List<List<Double>> or smth with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Greets! Need help solving the following:

Suppose we I need to store in entity  groups of values of Double, e.g.

```
M1: {M1.1, M1.2, ..., M1.10}
M2: {M2.1, M2.2, ..., M2.15}
...
M10: {M10.1, M10.2,..., M10.5}
```

These values get set via JSP by the client.

How do I store them in entity?
I lack understanding and examples of how to store `List<List<Double>>` or `List<ArrayList<Double>>`, or `double[][]`, etc...
Googled it, but never found the answer..
Would appreciate some help!!

Comment: What kind of table will save this information_

Comment: `List<ArrayList<>>` in any case is redundant compared to `List<List<>>`. The only difference is that you put a constraint on the enclosed `List` implementation in the first case. If you use Guava, have a look at `MultiMap`.

Answer (score 0):

Before you figure out how to use Hibernate to store the data, you need to figure out how the data is going to be represented in the database. Once you have that, mapping from Java to SQL becomes a lot clearer.

First thing you want to do, is figure out how to store lists of numbers. The most straight-forward way of doing so is creating two tables:

1. A NumbersList table with an ID and some additional data related to the list.
2. A NumbersListEntry table with three fields: ListId (which references the NumbersList table), EntryOrder(which is the position of the entry in the list) and Number (the actual number).

   Once you've got that, you can store lists of lists with two additional tables, very similar to the first ones:
3. ListOfList table with the ID and some data related to the list of list (owner, etc...).
4. A ListOfListEntry table with similar three fields: ListOfListId (references the ListOfList table), EntryOrder and NumbersListId (references the NumbersList table) .

Comment: Thank you, helped a lot. I will add new classes to my domain model using the advice You gave me. Guess there'll be no problem